# ADF deployment without making changes on trigger status

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am doing CI/CD on Azure Data Factory.

I do have a DEV instance and PROD instance of Azure Data Factory.

The deployment process is going smooth except one problem with the triggers.

I do have around 20 triggers in which 15 are in running state and 5 are stopped for a while in PROD.

Since DEV ADF is a development instance and i do not want to run any of the triggers in scheduled manner in development instance status of all triggers are set to stopped.

Currently the trigger status changes from DEV to PROD deployment is by replacing the string **'"runtimeState": "Stopped"', '"runtimeState": "Started"'** in the ARM template json file.
[image]

But this will start all of the triggers in the production after deployment along with the 5 triggers which are stopped for a while.

Is there any way to un touch the trigger status at the time of deployment in PROD and only add newly created trigger into PROD without touching the existing triggers in PROD?

Comment: `Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger` supports specifying TriggerName, you could start the triggers you want: `Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF" -TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Azure PowerShell Task to do this activity.

You can write a PowerShell script to Start/Stop trigger and place it in relevant pipeline.

In below case, I have stopped all triggers before deployment, you can add Pre or Post deployment step via PowerShell to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Yes! I am using this script provided by Microsoft for stopping and starting the triggers. But How should we edit this script in order to keep the status of trigger in PROD unchanged at the time of deployment?

Comment: As per my understanding the above script will stop all active triggers and after deployment script will start those triggers.

Comment: My requirement is bit different as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Okay, then I would recommend to remove the trigger definition from ARM Template for the triggers that you don't want to change, because I think that's the only possible way to do this, in this case you will have to change your ARM Template every time for Dev / Prod

Comment: @Antony those scripts wont start triggers on deployment for me. The script ran without error though, but no changes are reflected on the ADF UI

Comment: The triggers in DEV instance might be in stopped stage and while deploying, the same stage of triggers will be deployed. In that case you have to add an additional script to enable the triggers after the deployment.